# Python: use dict and list of tuples to create a numpy array

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have five key/value pairs in a python dict object:

```
dict1 = {0:3, 1:2, 2:2, 3:2, 4:3}
```

And I have a list of tuples:

```
list_of_tuples = [(0, 1), (0, 4), (2, 3)]
```

I want a numpy array of shape `(5, 5, 2)` that contains the value from the dict object for each tuple value. I get `5` from the number of keys in the dict object, and `2` from the number of values in each tuple.

That is:

- at position `(0, 1)` of the numpy array, I want a numpy array with values `(3, 2)`;
- at position `(0, 4)` of the numpy array, I want a numpy array with values `(3, 3)`;
- at position `(2, 3)` of the numpy array, I want a numpy array with values `(2, 2)`;
- at all other positions of the numpy array, I want a numpy array with values `(4, 4)`,

where I use `(4, 4)` as an indicator of an empty spot.

Is there a nice, Pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: Can you do this in some non-nice Pythonic way?  You know, with ordinary dictionary access and indexing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array of 4s using [`np.full`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.full.html) and then populate it:

```
a = np.full((5, 5, 2), 4)
for x, y in list_of_tuples:
     a[x, y] = dict1[x], dict1[y]
```